# Why does the increment not work in this case?

Tags: c, increment, ternary-operator

This particular loop fills an array which stands for a binary number bit by bit. What I'm trying to do is check the number entered by the user is either '0' or '1' using the ternary operator.

```
while (i < 8)
{
    printf("Bit %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &binaryNumber[i]);
    ((binaryNumber[i] == 1) || (binaryNumber[i] == 0)) ? i++ : printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n"), i--;
}
```

This code fails to increment i; so it loops infinitely and`printf("Bit %d: ", i)` always results in `Bit 0:`
The small `i--` hidden in the corner of the `:` is to re-access the previous element and overwrite it with a correct value.

However, adding `i++` under the ternary makes it work perfectly. My question is, why doesn't it work in the first case, and why *does* it work in the second?

Comment: Hello, operator precedence. `,` having the lowest precedence of all. The true source of your problem however, is the bad decision to write a one liner goo instead of using a plain old if-else on several lines.

Comment: Sane version: `if( (binaryNumber[i] == 1) || (binaryNumber[i] == 0) ) 
{
  i++; 
}
else
{
  printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n");
  i--;
}`.

Comment: I could do that, but it's just a practice program to familiarize myself with the ternary operator, so using plain old 'if-else' would be missing my own point :)

Comment: Let this serve as a warning for you! Never write code like this, please!

Comment: Yep so now you have learnt why the `?:` and `,` should both be avoided when possible. Beginners do well to stay clear of both of them. There are very few situations where `?:` is needed: function-like macros returning a value being one, simplifying repetitive switch statements being another. Similar with `,`, it should pretty much only be used in intricate, function-like macros. There's various subtle crap going on with both of these operators, that you might be better off not knowing, for now.

Comment: And to add to @Lundin's wise comment, note that the PHP guys have undone the way the ternary conditional operator is grouped. C, C++, and Java all do it the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is grouped as

```
(
    binaryNumber[i] == 1 || binaryNumber[i] == 0 
    ? i++ 
    : printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n")
), i--;
```

and compiles with defined behaviour since `printf` returns an `int` type and `,` is a sequencing point. In other words, `i` is *always* decremented.

Note that the bit between `?` and `:` is grouped as if it were in parentheses, but that's not true for the part after `:`. In other words, somewhat bizarrely, the expression

```
!(binaryNumber[i] == 1 || binaryNumber[i] == 0) 
? printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n"), i--
: i++
```

*would* behave the way you'd expect although relying on that is probably a step too far, even for me.

Comment: So basically, ```i++``` works, but is canceled out by the ```i--``` on the ```:``` side?

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55 Exactly. And the additional unconditional `i++` you add cancels out the `i--`.

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55 It works by bad luck, because `i++` gives an `int` and `printf` returns an `int`. The 2nd and 3rd operand of `?:` are of the same type so it is a valid statement as far as the compiler is concerned. Had you written `(void)printf(..` the code wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask from a comment for an explanation of why the second code snippet works? I grabbed a pen and paper and I still can't figure it out the 'why'

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55: Put the parentheses in `(printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n"), i--)` and it's clearer no?

Comment: Is it 'bumping up' the precedence of ```i--``` as @Lundin said?

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55: In a way yes. But think in terms of *grouping* rather than "precedence". Precedence is a corollary of the language grammar, and the grammar equips the operator with the grouping rule as I explain in my answer.

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55 `? printf("Binary bits can only be 0 or 1!\n"), i-- : i++` is some truly evil code. What happens is that after parsing `?`, the compiler grabs everything between `?` and `:` and checks if it forms a series of valid pre-processor tokens, so this has to do with how the pre-processor parses the grammar and it's an advanced subject. Then later on it checks if it's a valid expression, and it is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the ```?``` has a grouping rule, which is why we use the ```!```, and after ```:``` we have to group them ourselves?

Comment: @kirbysdreamland55: Yup, that's the one, but it would be wise to not rely on that, as I say in my answer. I only really mentioned it for a bit of fun.

Comment: This program was only a bit of fun with the ternary operator too, really. I was in over my head. I'll stick to if-else for now, as @Lundin wisely advised